# elasticsearch-rails empty results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I already did `Comment.import` and it returned 0, which means there were no errors during the import process.

I already did `Comment.__elasticsearch__.refresh_index!`

This is the model I'm using:

```
require "datamapper_adapter"

class Comment
  include DataMapper::Resource

  include Elasticsearch::Model

  property :id, Serial
  property :email, String
  property :author, String
  property :description, String
  property :created_at, DateTime

  belongs_to :picture

  validates_presence_of :email, :author, :description

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :id, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
      indexes :author, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
      indexes :description, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
    end
  end

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    as_json.except("picture_id", "created_at", "email", "_persistence_state", "_repository", "_id")
  end
end
```

And still all my queries to the elasticsearch return an empty array as hits.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/comments/comment/_search?pretty
{
    "took" : 35,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
    "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

I have data in my DB but I have no idea why it never gets filtered.
Any ideas why this is happening? This is driving me nuts

No matter what I do, hits is ALWAYS empty

Comment: Any chance to increase the DEBUG level to get more insights on what's going on during the import?

Comment: Download elasticsearch head (http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/), and connect to your ES instance. Does it contain the data you expect?

Comment: A quick way to see if there is data in the index is `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/comments/comment/_count'`

Answer (score 1):

could you try to add `type:string` to 
`indexes :description` and `indexes :author`

I also remember I had problem with as_json, for older rails versions it will include root attribute. 
Try to set it to false, you can do this globally or in the `as_json( root: false )`